# What FX is used at the end of the "What does the fox say" video?

Tags: fl-studio

I want to use that fx for my piano in fl studio 11
If you don't know what part is, or what video is you can try [here](https://youtu.be/jofNR_WkoCE).
The loop that I want to reproduce is from 2:26 to 2:28, and that *air* sound (like if you gather your lips tightly and blow) starts at 2:57 and is cutted by some silences, actually that's the only thing I want from that video.

If there's no efect that you know, then tech me how can I reach something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If I could make comments, this would be better as one. But what exactly are you looking for? The section sounds like just a standard synthesizer playing an arrpeggio (the synth should have a quick attack for the percussive nature, no sustain, and a medium-short release) and some super-compressed midi drums (maybe a closed high hat with some distortion and >10:1 compression ratio)..

As for the air sound. I listened four times, and the only thing I'm catching are splashy cymbals.

Both are fairly easy to get, but it takes fiddling with knobs more than finding instruction.

Hopefully someone gives you a better answer, or you could clarify what you're looking for.